# Datastax Enterprise inside AWS VPC using --customreservation

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am trying to get Datastax Enterprise to launch inside an AWS VPC on Private Subnets. Whilst I have had success using Cloudformation (by launching the cluster using `ec2-run-instances`) I was hoping to be able to launch the cluster using an AutoScalingGroup.

The --customreservation parameter seems to be the answer to this, but only works on the community version. Are there any plans to bring this to the enterprise version soon?

Is there an alternative way to launch a DSE cluster using Cloudformations other than customreservation?